# 'at' job fails: Script not found in the directory (raspberry pi)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, at

I am trying to run an 'at' job. The job is in ~/mydir/first.sh. It executes second.sh using (sh second.sh) which is in the same directory. I get an error saying that the file is not found.

This is very unusual as I am doing the exact same thing on another linux laptop and have no issues.

Comment: It's difficult to debug this as you don't say anything about what you have done. Please show exactly what commands you are issuing and _exactly_ what the error is that you are getting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an `at` job, the system creates a file with a copy of your current shell environment. This includes the `PATH` variable. Unless `PATH` contains '`.`' as one of the entries, then the `at` job will fail, just like if you tried to run it manually.

You can see what the system created where there will be a file under `/var/spool/atjobs/`.

Comment: Actually, `~/mydir/` should be in your path, or the script cd's to that directory and `'.'` is in your path.

Comment: Since the user is executing `second.sh` using `sh second.sh`, the `PATH` variable doesn't even enter into the equation. The only thing that matters is what the current working directory is.  With `at`, the directory from which `at` was invoked will be the working directory of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute path references in your scripts, I find that this is typically needed for cronjobs, and I assume the same applies to at.

I can’t add this as a comment, my reputation is not high enough.